# Rails: Create a custom UI for a single specific object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, user-interface, view

I've run into a problem I'm completely unsure how to approach.

I have an app for sharing architectural photos. Users `have_many` Photos, and users can create Collections which also `have_many` Photos.

Now I have one customer who is a big name in the industry who would like to work with me to create a totally customized Collection with a very different look and feel from "regular" collections, but essentially the same functionality underneath. I'd like to accommodate this request, but I really have no idea how to do it.

Given that I already have a functioning `Collection` model and `CollectionsController`, plus all the views, I'd like to re-use as much of that as possible. So, for instance, the custom Collection needs to override the user facing :show view, but *not* the admin :edit view.

How would you approach something like this?

I'm trying to understand the most efficient, DRY method for creating a completely custom UI for a single record in the database. I'd be very appreciative of suggestions, including links to articles / books etc, as I haven't been able to find much in this area.

Answer (score 1):

I would allow the creation of [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) view templates associated with a User and/or Collection (if you want both - per-user templates with per-collection variations - use a polymorphic association) and of course fall back to your default view (also built with Liquid for consistency and reference) for all cases where no custom template is found.

***Edit to add suggested details:***

Any custom templates should be stored in the database (I would add a test/preview function so the user entering a custom template has the chance to verify their template before publishing it):

```
# Table name custom_templates
# id               :integer
# templatable_type :string
# templatable_id   :integer
# contents         :text
class CustomTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :templatable, :polymorphic => true
end
class User
  has_one :custom_template, :as => :templatable    
end
class Collection
  has_one :custom_template, :as => :templatable
end
```

In your controller action, look for a custom template:

```
custom_template   = @collection.custom_template
custom_template ||= @user.custom_template
@custom_template = Liquid::Template.parse(custom_template.contents) if custom_template
```

In your view, either render the custom template or your default template partial:

```
<% if @custom_template -%>
  <%= @custom_template.render(_hash_of_objects_to_pass_to_liquid_template_) %>
<% else -%>
  <%= render :partial => 'default' %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: How does using Liquid work for the end-user? Do I store their template in the database or something... How does the controller know which template to use? I've never done anything like that before so I'm really pretty lost.

Comment: Yes, the custom templates would be stored in the database, while the default view is still stored in the filesystem.

Comment: I'll try to provide more details in the next day or so - I'm headed out now for a while.